# Axios POST request error in headers in Vue2

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am new to javascript and Vue.js

I am making a POST API call in Vuejs using axios and my backend is in node.js. I am getting error in the authorisation. It works fine in postman

My POST API Call is as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
    import router from '../router'
    import axios from 'axios'

    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/'
    const LOGIN_URL = API_URL + 'login'

    export default {
    login(credentials, redirect) {
    console.log(LOGIN_URL)
    axios.post(LOGIN_URL,{
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic YWtzaGF5OmFrc2hheQ==',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
    'email': credentials.email,
    'password': credentials.password
    }
  }).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
  router.push(redirect)
  }).catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
  })
  }
  }
```

When I make the api request my javascript console shows

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500(Internal Server Error)
```

and my server console shows error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

here username is username in basic authorization.

Comment: in your data post you are not sendig username field, just email and password, i think you should include username.

Comment: there is not username required by the server. Username field is for header authorization

Comment: You haven't included all of the relevant code. The error clearly reads that it's trying to read the property `username` from a variable which is empty or doesn't have `username` defined.

Comment: We would need to see the server code to be of any more help. What object is the server trying to read the "username" field from?